# How to download CGI page as a html with all the stuff (js, images, css and etc) using WGET?

Tags: javascript, html, linux, terminal, wget

When I use Google Chrome's "Save as.." the cgi page is being downloaded as one single html and another folder with all required stuff in order to display it correctly offline. I tried many parameter but nothing worked properly as I expected. Also -p doesn't work.

GNU Wget 1.14 built on linux-gnu.
When I use -p option, get robots.txt and the .cgi file itself.

Can it be like this because of the cookies? Is there option that may fix this problem?
Is there another way? I mean for example if I put some parameters to chromium in the terminal.

Answer (score 1):

Quoting from the man page:

> ‘-p’ ‘--page-requisites’
>
> This option causes Wget to download all the files that are necessary
>   to properly display a given HTML page. This includes such things as
>   inlined images, sounds, and referenced stylesheets.

Answer (score 0):

Problem was that I needed to use cookies to pass the log in session. So --load-cookies seems to solve my problem.